# Javascript / JQuery interactive timeline with expanding entries that are centered relative to container on click

Tags: jquery

I'm in the process of developing a timeline.  The concept is that when an entry in the timeline is clicked, the entire timeline is centered on that entry and the entry expands.

I have a working demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/A3YhX/9/

I have manually set the css left position (to center the timeline on the clicked item) using the jquery index method (which gives me a numerical value for each item in the timeline when I click it).

What I want to be able to do is have javascript/jquery do the math for me so that if I add items, change their widths, change the size of the container element, etc  the jquery function will automatically calculate the css left position.

I know there are plugins out there that do exactly this, but I threw this together from scratch this morning before doing any dissection on existing solutions.

Any and all help/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

mckinselberg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pos = x * -35 + 150;
```

That'll do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/B6bqM/

Comment: @mckinselberg np :) glad to help.